# How can I customize the notification from Google Notifier and Google+Growl?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, notifications, growl, google-notifier

As best I can tell, Google and Growl use the Google Notifier Growl notification instead of displaying its own.

The GrowlMail plugin lets you configure what info is displayed upon receipt of a new message.

Is there a way to configure what is displayed by the Google Notifier a la GrowlMail--in other words, to choose that I just want to see e.g. that there is a new message and the time, but not the sender or body,  etc, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start *Google+Growl Utility* and it presents to you the following screen (after installation, if you haven't already done so):

[image]

Seems pretty extensive to me.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. I must have installed it, not paid attention to that window, and come back later looking for a preference pane and not found it since it wasn't in Growl prefs. Thanks!